# Error while opening xlsx file when downloaded using webclient.downloadfile

Tags: c#

i am trying to download a file from a site to a folder

```
TheWebclientL.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(zUserIdL, zPasswordL);
  TheWebclientL.DownloadFile(zSharePointURLPathL, "E:\FolderOutputs\ExcelTemplate\Lookup.xlsx");
```

its not throwing me any error while downloading.

while trying to open it,its given me a error

Excel cannot open the file because its file format or file extension is invalid

Comment: Are you sure you have downloaded the correct file and not a html document? You could have a problem accessing the file on the sharepoint site for instance. Then the file you download would be a html file and not an excel file. Try to open the downloaded file in a text editor and check.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue,the webclient was not able to access the file in the sharepoint site

Comment: Tell us how did you fixed it.